# UWP app freezing every 30 seconds

Tags: uwp, freeze

Ok, I have this UWP app driving me nuts...
The app freezes every 30 seconds or so, and only becomes responsive for 30 seconds at a time...  When it freezes, there is no visible code that is running or break point that gets hit, no background thread / task, no memory increase.  CPU usage is fine.
No exception either in the output window.  Only the app is freezing, nothing else.
When it freezes, moving the mouse over the app works, but the controls do not get highlighted on hover, no control gets focus when clicked, etc...
There does not appear anything of significance in the Windows event log.  When the app unfreezes, Visual Studio does not report any changes in the output window either.  I am at the point of commenting out pieces of code one at a time, but this is a slow and painful process.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated to help narrowing down this issue a little faster...

Comment: Your app isn’t frozen since it responds to mouse event (mouse over), also as you mentioned the indicators for frozen apps are just ‘normal’. I guess there is some opaque layer that you cannot click through. You can use the visual tree visualizer to see if there is any.

Comment: Also try running performance analysis (if your version of VS has it).

Comment: When the app freezes, pause it through the debugger. Inspecting the threads' call stacks should be your first instinct, particularly your GUI thread(s).

Comment: @kennyzx - I meant the mouse is moving on the screen, but the app below is not responding to anything, not even on hover.  The app indicators at the top of the screen are also frozen.

Comment: @IInspectable - when the app freezes, and I pause the debugger, the current thread is Main Thread twinapi.appcore.dll!5d6669f9.  Nothing else.

Comment: Look at the call stack. Be sure to load symbols.

Comment: I would be very interested in debugging this, as long as you can upload your code to GitHub (removing any sensitive data of course).

Comment: Chances are when you try to make a minimal example to repro this issue you find the root cause yourself.

Comment: Call stack says "global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());"
Nothing else.

Comment: @kennyzx I'll keep your offer in mind.  Thanks!  I'm going to keep troubleshooting for the time being.  Something I noticed is that freezing seems to occur when there are more elements showing on the screen (say 150 items in a gridview, *or* a pivot with several pivot items).  The weird thing is that this was not happening in an earlier version of the app, with the same screens!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be related to debug mode only running Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.8.2).  Installing a side-loaded release package did not have that issue.
I reinstalled Visual Studio 15.7.6 and debug mode is apparently running fine, without any freezing.  I am not sure what caused this but at least I've learned not to be on the bleeding edge...